# Build a Platform API for public

Tags: api, platforms

I am looking for some advices, resources or articles about how to expose a Platform API to outside developers.

My main concern is what is the standards or best approach to do that, basically I have a set of REST API services of the platform and need to understand how to address the following issus :

- API Hosting and Management in general (should we use online api management tools like [apigee](http://www.apigee.com) or [mashrey](http://www.mashery.com)?)
- Developer Keys, permissions
- Developer tools, documentations
- throttling
- Reporting
- Logging/Auditing
- Authentication and Authorization

It is also great if you can point out to some articles that explain how Facebook or Twitter or Google are doing this, or abstract architecture and management best practices on how to open Platform API to the public users.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: read the Facebook and Amazon development documents.

(Don't read Google, some folks think they're not as good at creating an API.  Read this to see what mistakes Google may have made. https://plus.google.com/112678702228711889851/posts/eVeouesvaVX)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

http://aws.amazon.com/

These documents will cover most of your questions.  They will show a number of good practices.  You'll have to choose which you think is best.

Comment: I find amazon documentation hard to follow, any ideas how to get to authentication/authorization documents in amazon aws website?